# Dynamically created jQuery UI dialog error after jQuery 2.2.0 upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I created a few Dialogs using jQuery UI 1.11.4. I am trying to upgrade my jQuery to 2.2.0 from 1.11.3. I receive an error when trying to initialize my jQuery UI dialog.

```
 $deptdialog = $('<div id="deptdialog"></div>')
    .html('<iframe id="deptiframe" style="width:100%;" scrolling="no" src="" />')
    .dialog({ ... });
```

After initializing it like this..

```
$deptdialog .dialog('open');
```

I'm receiving this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageYOffset' of null
```

And when  stepping into jQuery it errors on this line

```
win = getWindow( doc );
top: box.top + win.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
```

win ends up being null. Anyone point me in the direction of why this is happening, or how to fix it? Is it because I'm loading a dynamic iFrame in the dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get error only if I declare the dialog object (i.e.:  $deptdialog) before document ready in my snippet, otherwise it works fine.

```js
$(function () {
  $deptdialog = $('<div id="deptdialog"></div>')
  .html('<iframe id="deptiframe" style="width:100%;" scrolling="no" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" />')
  .dialog({autoOpen: false});

  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $deptdialog.dialog('open');
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<button id="btn">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was my issue.